# Why can't I set like so in a setter in C++?

Tags: c++

I tried to code a setter function in a C++ object like this.

```
void set_acceleration(double acceleration) {
  acceleration_(acceleration);
}
```

where `acceleration_` is a private variable. However, g++ issued an compile-time error:

```
'((Car*)this)->Car::acceleration_' cannot be used as a function.
```

I know that `acceleration_` is a `double`, not a function, but why can't I set it this way? I set `acceleration_` like that when I construct a `Car` object.

Comment: Uhm... because the syntax for setting a value is the assignment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax is illegal unless you're initializing the variable, either upon declaration (*this will create a new variable, not modify your class member, so this isn't what you want*):

```
double acceleration_(acceleration);
```

or in a member initialization list:

```
className() : acceleration_(acceleration)
{
}
```

You're looking for assignment:

```
acceleration_ = acceleration;
```